# How to mock IPv6 environment where ISP does not support it?

Tags: ios, ipv6

AppStore rejected my app saying it does not support IPv6. Seems like my server does not support IPv6. Now even though I get my server API fixed to support IPv6, how do I check it here in India, as none of the ISP here supports IPv6.

Comment: You need to test it on an IPv6-only network, as Apple does. Apple has instructions on how to set up such a network.

Comment: Yes, tried those, but didn't work. Anyways thanks @RonMaupin

Comment: This is not a programming question. Please post this question in a more appropriate place related to servers and networking.

Comment: Apple's instructions did not fully help me - I asked a question over there at Ask Different - maybe some detail helps you: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/214212/79163

Comment: Follow [the directions Apple gives you](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW16). If it "didn't work" then it isn't sufficient to just say it "didn't work". You need to describe the actual problem.

Comment: @rmaddy This _is_ a question about programming tools, and certainly does not belong on [sf].

Comment: You don't need to do anything with your server. Your server doesn't need to support IPv6. Any changes that are needed are with the client.

Comment: Thats true @MichaelHampton. Its more of an issue on the client.

Comment: Thanks @RainerSchwarze. Tried that but still the tests say 'no IPv6'. Also the internet stopped as soon as it was switched to IPv6.